# Hide derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance

i'm new to C# or OOP in general and was wondering if next is possible with inheritance:

i want to setup a communication link and want to be able to use udp or serial communication. 
So i define an abstract base class 'Link' with methods .open, .close, .send, .receive
From this base class i derive 2 classes 'LinkUdp' and 'LinkSerial' and override the 4 methods

Now is it possible to directly write code with an object to the 'Link' class ? I mean like:

> Link myLink = new Link("10.0.0.1"); //now the compiler knows to
>   use LinkUdp class
>   Link myLink = new Link("COM1"); //compiler knows
>   to use LinkSerial class

or do i have to write my code dedicated like:

> LinkUdp myLink = new LinkUdp("10.0.0.1");

Hope this is clear enough...
Thanks

edit:
i would like to use the 'Link' class so i can pass the object on to a subclass without having to write 2 different implementations:
so after this i have a class

> CommunicationHandler myComm = new CommunicationHandler(myLink);

and then this handler doesn't have to worry about me using udp or serial...

Comment: I think you have to implement the Factory Pattern use this link for understanding http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

Comment: If `Link` is an abstract class, then you can never directly create an instance of it. `new Link(...)` is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to let the compiler choose which type to instantiate based on just a variable name (unless you use reflection or a factory to create the right instance for you).

This is possible though and it shows one of the benefits of inheritance:

```
Link myLink;
myLink = new LinkUdp("10.0.0.1");
myLink = new LinkSerial("10.0.0.1");
```

No matter what follows, `myLink` can be either of them. The type used is `Link`, which allows your application to be as generic as possible.

Comment: so, as in my edit above: i could pass this myLink to another method and it wouldn't have any problems to call myLink.Open() for example. As long as LinkUdp.Open() and LinkSerial.Open() both exist ? Then this should be the answer to my problem. Thanks

Comment: Yes, no worries about that. Just use `Link` as type for your parameter.

Comment: And those methods should be defined in the base class, possibly `abstract` with an implementation in the derived classes.

Answer (score 7):

No a constructor for a class can only return that class' type.  You could alternatively have a static Create function (factory pattern):

```
Link myLink = Link.Create("10.0.0.1");
```

eg

```
public static Link Create(string something)
{
    if (//determine that "something" is an IP address))
        return new LinkUdp(something);
    else
        return new LinkSerial(something);

}
```